# Cannot re-add view in a MVC4 razor project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am unable to re-add a partial view after removing it. VS says the file already exists. I checked the .csproj and the .sln file for a reference but could not find any. I also did a clean get of all the source from TFS and still cannot add. Anyone know where to remove the old references or whatever blocks the addition?

Comment: Is the view file itself deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS is complaining that the file exists on disk, not in the project.

Delete it in Windows Explorer (or after clicking Show All Files) and try again.